# directed graph root

Tags: graph-theory

I have this question :

false or true ?
A finite directed graph that his digraph is clique then he most have a root.

I tried to solve it by trying to show an euler path.

thank you in advance.

Comment: where "root" means "source", I suppose?
In this case is false, for example with $n=2,3$ nodes

Comment: @Exodd yeah exactly, sorry for my weak language.

Comment: @Exodd, i think you are wrong because in this case the directed graph does have a source. maybe my question isn't clear enough ?

Answer (score 1):

In case with "root"/"source" you mean a vertex with in-degree 0 and with "clique" you mean complete graph, then the answer is *false*.

For example, consider the graph $G=(V,E) \text{ with } V=\{v_1, v_2, v_3\} \text{ and } E=\{(v_1,v_2),(v_2,v_3),(v_3,v_1)\}$.